# Operator on a multivariable function in a sum

Tags: functions, operators

I need to define an operator that does as follow for any function $h_m$.

$\qquad O[h_m](k,M,b,l_{max})=\sum_{l\neq (0,m)}^{l_{max}}il \left (h_l(k,M,b,l_{max}) b_{m-l}(k)- c_l\partial_k h_{m-l}(k,M,b,l_{max})\right )$

But it is very difficult (it is the first time I have to use operators

I try so far

```
op[k_, M_, p_, m_, lmax_] = 
  Function[{f}, (-I Sum[ l ((h [##] &[k, M, p, l, lmax]) b[k,
          m - l] - (Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0][h] [##] &[k, M, p, 
           m - l, lmax]) c[k, m - l]), {l, 
      Complement[Range[-lmax, lmax], {0, m}]}])]
```

But that does not seems to provide the right result.

Do you have any idea to write this in a proper way?

Comment: Does $h$ always have five arguments, subscript included?

Comment: Yes (or at least it is not a problem to do so).

Comment: The syntax is different for `Function`. Or one can just delete it: `op[k_, M_, p_, m_, 
  lmax_] := (-I Sum[
    l ((h[##] &[k, M, p, l, lmax]) b[k, 
         m - l] - (Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0][h][##] &[k, M, p, m - l, 
          lmax])` etc

Comment: But then how I replace h by the desired function? Just with                        op[k, M, p,m,lmax] /. (h->f)  ?  It works, in fact. thanks.